# Path file I send with => Send to C# script

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a console script working so fine...but I made a GUI for that script and now I don't know how can I get the full path for that file I send?

I get only this one: `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]` but I get the folder from the script source.

It's a small WPF app but I'm stuck right now. (I searched a lot on google and I don't find anything good)

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Download_subtitles_GUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Download_subtitles_GUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Title="Download subtitles" Height="129" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Margin="10,10,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" FontSize="14" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock2" Margin="10,30,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" FontSize="14" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock3" Margin="10,60,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" FontSize="14" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

```
namespace Download_subtitles_GUI
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBlock1.Text = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: do not post code in the comments, edit the original question and post the code there

Comment: Is the problem that `TextBlock1.Text` only contains the name of the file, not the complete path to it?

Comment: Nope. With that code I get the path from script (c:\) but I need the path for the file (D:\Downloads\...) I send to script

Comment: I added a shortcut from the script here `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` , and I need to get this: `D:\Downloads\TESTING` but I get only this `C:\Working\C#\Download subtitles GUI\Subtitles GUI\bin\Debug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you need is:

```
TextBlock1.Text = string.Join(" ", Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1));
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thank you.